# "sbox_fatal_memory_exceeded" - Javascript Countdown Function

Tags: javascript, performance, memory

I am fairly new to JS and don't know much.
So I tried to make a simple countdown for work, so I can see how long I have to work. It takes the actual time and just subtracts it from the time till I have to work. So very simple.
When I keep the website open for more than 20 mins, it crashes and Chrome/Edge/Firefox displays the ERROR message: ''SBOX_FATAL_MEMORY_EXCEEDED".

I think, due to the fact, that I am recalling the function with an unaccasary amount of ifs, the Browser gets drained quickly out of memory. That's at least what I think. But I can not get it to work. Nevermind how I rewrite my function, it still crashes.

Would be happy if someone can help me, or link me a similar StackOverflow question, 'cause the few results for this error in combination with js didn't help me.

Here is the JS code:

```js
//CSS ELEMETNS
var helloText = document.getElementById("welcomeText");
var textFiller = document.getElementById("fillerText");
var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");
var motivationText = document.getElementById("motivationText");
var btn = document.getElementById("button");

//JS VARs
let date, hrs, mins, secs;
let date = new Date();

//main function to check which day it is, and which function to call
function clock() {
  let day = date.getDay());
  if (day == 0 || day == 6) {
    weekend();
  } else if (day == 5) {
    friday();
  } else {
    otherDay();
  }
}


//Text to display if it is sun or sat
function weekend() {
  helloText.innerHTML = "Juhu!";
  countdown.innerHTML = "Es ist Wochenende!";
  textFiller.innerHTML = "";
  btn.style.display = "none";
}

//Function to execute when it is friday
function friday() {
  hrs = date.getHours();
  mins = date.getMinutes();
  secs = date.getSeconds();

  hrs = hrs < 10 ? `0${hrs}` : hrs;
  mins = mins < 10 ? `0${mins}` : mins;
  secs = secs < 10 ? `0${secs}` : secs;

  if (hrs >= 14 || hrs < 7) {
    if ((((helloText.innerHTML != "Yeah!" &&
            countdown.innerHTML != "You can go home!") &&
          textFiller.innerHTML != "") &&
        btn.style.display != "none")) {
      helloText.innerHTML = "Yeah!";
      countdown.innerHTML = "You can go home!";
      textFiller.innerHTML = "";
      btn.style.display = "none";
    }
  } else {
    if (hrs < 10) {
      if (helloText.innerHTML != "Good Morning!" &&
        motivationText.innerHTML !=
        "Man, it is still early in the morning...") {
        helloText.innerHTML = "Good Morning!";
        motivationText.innerHTML =
          "Man, it is still early in the morning...";
      }
    }
    if (hrs == 10 || hrs > 10) {
      if (helloText.innerHTML != "Hello!" &&
        motivationText.innerHTML !=
        "Stay concentrated! The morning is already over!") {
        helloText.innerHTML = "Hello!";
        motivationText.innerHTML =
          "Stay concentrated! The morning is already over!";
      }
    }
    if (hrs == 12 || hrs > 12) {
      if (motivationText.innerHTML != "You almost got it!") {
        motivationText.innerHTML = "You almost got it!";
      }
    }
    if (hrs == 13 || hrs > 13) {
      if (motivationText.innerHTML !=
        "Finally! The last hour!") {
        motivationText.innerHTML =
          "Finally! The last hour!";
      }
    }
    hrs = 13 - hrs;
    mins = 59 - mins;
    secs = 60 - secs;
    if (hrs < 10) {
      hrs = "0" + hrs;
    }
    if (mins < 10) {
      mins = "0" + mins;
    }
    if (secs < 10) {
      secs = "0" + secs;
    }

    let time = `${hrs}:${mins}:${secs}`;
    setInterval(clock, 1000);
    countdown.innerText = time;
  }
}

//otherday() is the same as friday(), just with different hours
```

Comment: When it is friday, you will execute setInterval every second

Comment: When posting a snippet, please make it a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script was not working at all

This works. Take it from there

I moved the setInterval outside all functions and new Date inside clock

```js
//CSS ELEMETNS
var helloText = document.getElementById("welcomeText");
var textFiller = document.getElementById("fillerText");
var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");
var motivationText = document.getElementById("motivationText");
var btn = document.getElementById("button");

//JS VARs
let date, hrs, mins, secs;


//main function to check which day it is, and which function to call
function clock() {
  date = new Date();
  let day = date.getDay();
  if (day == 0 || day == 6) {
    weekend();
  } else if (day == 5) {
    friday();
  } else {
    // otherDay();
    friday()
  }



  //Text to display if it is sun or sat
  function weekend() {
    helloText.innerHTML = "Juhu!";
    countdown.innerHTML = "Es ist Wochenende!";
    textFiller.innerHTML = "";
    btn.style.display = "none";
  }

  //Function to execute when it is friday
  function friday() {

    hrs = date.getHours();
    mins = date.getMinutes();
    secs = date.getSeconds();

    hrs = hrs < 10 ? `0${hrs}` : hrs;
    mins = mins < 10 ? `0${mins}` : mins;
    secs = secs < 10 ? `0${secs}` : secs;
    let time = `${hrs}:${mins}:${secs}`;
    countdown.innerText = time;

    if (hrs >= 14 || hrs < 7) {
      if ((((helloText.innerHTML != "Yeah!" &&
              countdown.innerHTML != "You can go home!") &&
            textFiller.innerHTML != "") &&
          btn.style.display != "none")) {
        helloText.innerHTML = "Yeah!";
        countdown.innerHTML = "You can go home!";
        textFiller.innerHTML = "";
        btn.style.display = "none";
      }
    } else {
      if (hrs < 10) {
        if (helloText.innerHTML != "Good Morning!" &&
          motivationText.innerHTML !=
          "Man, it is still early in the morning...") {
          helloText.innerHTML = "Good Morning!";
          motivationText.innerHTML =
            "Man, it is still early in the morning...";
        }
      }
      if (hrs == 10 || hrs > 10) {
        if (helloText.innerHTML != "Hello!" &&
          motivationText.innerHTML !=
          "Stay concentrated! The morning is already over!") {
          helloText.innerHTML = "Hello!";
          motivationText.innerHTML =
            "Stay concentrated! The morning is already over!";
        }
      }
      if (hrs == 12 || hrs > 12) {
        if (motivationText.innerHTML != "You almost got it!") {
          motivationText.innerHTML = "You almost got it!";
        }
      }
      if (hrs == 13 || hrs > 13) {
        if (motivationText.innerHTML !=
          "Finally! The last hour!") {
          motivationText.innerHTML =
            "Finally! The last hour!";
        }
      }
      hrs = 13 - hrs;
      mins = 59 - mins;
      secs = 60 - secs;
      if (hrs < 10) {
        hrs = "0" + hrs;
      }
      if (mins < 10) {
        mins = "0" + mins;
      }
      if (secs < 10) {
        secs = "0" + secs;
      }

    }
  }
}

setInterval(clock, 1000);

//otherday() is the same as friday(), just with different hours
```

```html
<span id="welcomeText"></span>
<span id="fillerText"></span>
<span id="motivationText"></span>
<span id="countdown"></span>
<button type="button" id="button">Button</button>
```